# jd-gui 0.3.3 - failing on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, decompiler

I think that jd-gui is one of the best Java decompilers; and am I happily using on Linux for quite some time. Today I tried to invoke it on Ubuntu 12.04; and I get this error message:

> jd-gui 
>   PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE failed.

Any idea anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have [PaX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX) enabled in your kernel.
If so, you use [paxctl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/paxctl) to control memory protection flags on a per binary basis. On Ubuntu 12.04 there are no issues with launching jdgui by default, if you have not explicitly hardened your system.

If paxctl does not help you to resolve the issue, check if you have antivirus or other hardening on your system that does not really respect PaX flags. I know for a fact that Sym*****AntiVirus for Linux is blocking jdgui. Once you get rid of the kernel modules then everything is back to normal. Run `lsmod | grep sym` to confirm if the modules are loaded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Completely forgot about this question; and yes you are right; the problem was Symantec Antivurs.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk